# How to use RequestBodyAdvice

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class RequestBodyAdviceChain implements RequestBodyAdvice {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(MethodParameter methodParameter, Type type,
            Class< ? extends HttpMessageConverter< ? >> aClass) {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Object handleEmptyBody(Object o, HttpInputMessage httpInputMessage, MethodParameter methodParameter,
            Type type, Class< ? extends HttpMessageConverter< ? >> aClass) {
        return o;
    }

    @Override
    public HttpInputMessage beforeBodyRead(HttpInputMessage httpInputMessage, MethodParameter methodParameter,
            Type type, Class< ? extends HttpMessageConverter< ? >> aClass) throws IOException {
        return httpInputMessage;
    }

    @Override
    public Object afterBodyRead(Object o, HttpInputMessage httpInputMessage, MethodParameter methodParameter, Type type,
            Class< ? extends HttpMessageConverter< ? >> aClass) {
        return o;
    }
}
```

Ideally, flow should reach these function first and then go to controller but it's not working.

Comment: Did you get solution to this issue?

Answer (score 0):

`@ControllerAdvice` component should be registered in Spring's context as any other component. Make sure Spring sees this component, e.q. by including it in `@ComponentScan` (Java Config) or in `<context:component-scan/>` (xml way). The preferred context to register it would be the Dispatcher Servlet's one.

Answer (score 0):

You should extend `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` directly for the more specific configuration (instead of `@EnableWebMvc` if you follow this approach).

Then override this method `org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport#createRequestMappingHandlerAdapter` and set your `RequestBodyAdvice` manually.

This should work

Comment: I made the post to blog how to use the RequestBodyAdvice with real example: http://deventh.blogspot.com/2017/07/spring-mvc-requestbodyadvice-or-how-to.html