# Spring RequestBodyAdvice not being triggered

Tags: spring-mvc

I declared a `@ControllerAdvice` which implements `RequestBodyAdvice`. My problem that its not being triggered. I have a `ResponseBodyAdvice` in the same package, which is working as expected.

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class RestPreProcessingAdvice implements RequestBodyAdvice {

  @Override
  public boolean supports(final MethodParameter methodParameter, final Type targetType,
      final Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
    return checkIfElegiable(...);
  }

  @Override
  public Object handleEmptyBody(final Object body, final HttpInputMessage inputMessage, final MethodParameter parameter,
      final Type targetType, final Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
    return body;
  }

  @Override
  public HttpInputMessage beforeBodyRead(final HttpInputMessage inputMessage, final MethodParameter parameter,
      final Type targetType, final Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) throws IOException {
    return doSomeProcessing(...);
  }

  @Override
  public Object afterBodyRead(final Object body, final HttpInputMessage inputMessage, final MethodParameter parameter,
      final Type targetType, final Class<? extends HttpMessageConverter<?>> converterType) {
    return body;
  }
}
```

I debugged and am seeing that this `@ControllerAdvice` is being found in `ControllerAdviceBean.findAnnotatedBeans()`. But why its not triggered I couldn't find out so far.

I guess some other people are having the similar problems. 
See [How to use RequestBodyAdvice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35277727/how-to-use-requestbodyadvice) and [Spring RequestBodyAdvice is not picking up by the mock MVC frame work, how ever it is working for ResponseBodyAdvice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36419353/spring-requestbodyadvice-is-not-picking-up-by-the-mock-mvc-frame-work-how-ever).

Comment: Hi. Did you ever figure this out? I am having a similar issue.

Comment: Unfortunately not. Keep me posted if you figure it out.

Comment: I was actually trying to load the JsonViewRequestBodyAdvice implementation which I found out is automatically added if Jackson is on the classpath. But, in finding that out, I did find one solution. See below.

Comment: this advice only triggers if you send a post request

Answer (score 5):

In your controller method try annotating the method parameter with `@RequestBody`.

E.g.

```
@RestController
public class MyController{

   @RequestMapping(.......)
   public MyResponse greetings(@RequestBody MyRequest requestObject){
        //implementation
   }

}
```

`RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor` class (and its base class `AbstractMessageConverterMethodArgumentResolver`) are responsible for invoking the various abstract methods (`beforeBodyRead`, `afterBodyRead` etc) of `RequestBodyAdvice`. `RequestMappingHandlerAdapter` would choose `RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor` to process the request only if the controller method's arguement is **annotated** with `@RequestBody`. We can see this logic implemented in the `supportsParameter` method of `RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor`.

I think an alternate way would be to create our *own* `MethodProcessor` by *extending* `RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor` and *overriding* its `supportsParameter` method to put our own logic. I have not tested this, though.

Comment: How about RequestMapping with no Request body.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration to set the RequestBodyAdvice.

```
@Configuration
public class WebConfig extends DelegatingWebMvcConfiguration {

    public RequestBodyAdvice myRequestBodyAdvice(){
        return new MyRequestBodyAdvice();
    }


    public RequestMappingHandlerAdapter requestMappingHandlerAdapter() {
        RequestMappingHandlerAdapter adapter = 
super.requestMappingHandlerAdapter();
        adapter.setRequestBodyAdvice(Arrays.asList(myRequestBodyAdvice()));
        return adapter;
    }
}
```

See section 22.16.13 in [Spring Framework Docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)